# Get best-selling product based on year

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a `sql query` to get best product of each year from a table . I have grouped the `product-id` and sum the qty to get the total number of products per id.

I converted the `datetime` function into year to get the year but output is wrong..

Anyone can help me with this?

```
SELECT Year(ModifiedDate), ProductID, SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQuantity
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY ProductID, year(ModifiedDate)
having count(*) > 3000
ORDER BY SUM(OrderQty) DESC
```

Comment: What does "the output is wrong" mean?  You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I think the `having` clause  may cause the problem.

Comment: In getting nothing in output. I want best selling product based on year. And it's returning nothing

Comment: Is modifiedDate the right column to be looking at?  Is there a createdDate?

Comment: Yes. it's correct.

Comment: query is working fine if the set having condition to 2000. but if i set it to 3000 it return nothing. if i use this "having count(*) > 2000"  so i get two records. first of 2013 which return total quantity 3913 and record of 2014 with total quantity 2902. but when i change condition to this "having count(*) > 3000 " it return nothing. but it should return the 2013 record.

Comment: Simplify the problem, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Have a look at Window functions - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> query is working fine if the set having condition to 2000. but if i
>   set it to 3000 it return nothing. if i use this "having count() >
>   2000" so i get two records. first of 2013 which return total quantity
>   3913 and record of 2014 with total quantity 2902. but when i change
>   condition to this "having count() > 3000 " it return nothing. but it
>   should return the 2013 record

You select the sum of OrderQty, yet you filter on the count and expect it to be the same. Count is the number of records, it doesn't care about the actual values in the records.

When you filter with

```
having sum(OrderQty) > 3000
```

you will only get the 2013 record.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in two-part.
I) create a temporary table for year-wise, id wise sum of qty.

```
create table tempSaleOrderDetail as select year(ModifiedDate) year,sum(OrderQty) orderqty, ProductID from Sales.SalesOrderDetail group by year(ModifiedDate), productId order by 1 desc,2 desc;
```

II) Fetch the data.

```
select A.* from tempSaleOrderDetail A inner join (select year ,max(orderqty) orderqty from tempSaleOrderDetail group by year) B on A.year=B.year and A.orderqty=B.orderqty ;
```

If any year has more than one Id's performance is same so this query will give both results.